# Stack Overflow on lisp changing 2 elements on a list

Tags: common-lisp

I have this function to swap two elements on a list:

```
(defun change-path (List)
    (setf len (list-length List))
    (setf x1 (random len))
    (setf x2 (random len))
    (setf e1 (get-n-element List x1))
    (setf e2 (get-n-element List x2))

    (changeElem (changeElem List x2 e1) x1 e2)
)
```

the function `get-n-element` is working fine, and the `change-path` works fine sometimes, but when I pass for exemple a list of list it always return program stack overflow, what can I do to fix this?

```
(defun changeElem (List pos novo)
    (cond ((null List) nil)
        ((zerop (1- pos)) (cons novo (changeElem (rest List) (1- pos) novo)))
        (t (cons (first List) (changeElem (rest Lista) (1- pos) novo)))

    )
)

(defun get-n-element (Lista n)
    (cond ((zerop (1- n)) (first Lista))
        (t (get-n-element (rest Lista) (1- n)))
    )
)
```

Comment: The stack overflow error should contain information about the problem. Probably it comes from changeElem, but please post the missing definitions. Secondly, you are using setf on undeclared variables (you should be using let* in this case). The unspecified but common behavior in that case is to mutate the (global) symbol value (e.g. x1, x2). Side-effects to global variables is not good practice. If you did the same in changeElem and it is recursive, then you mutate global variables recursively, which is probably bad in terms of reentrency. Please add more details.

Comment: I edited the question, to post also the changeElem. I dont use the variables anywere else.

Comment: And I tried to use let, but it was returning an error so i changed to setf

Comment: Oh... I'm stupid... x1 and x2 should be from 1 to len and on that code they are being calculated from 0 to len-1 and on function get-n-element generated the error